# Java Process getInputStream vs. getOutputStream

Tags: java, process, input, stream

I'm a bit confused about the streams... which is which?

Simply, which stream should I use to catch the output of my Process, and which stream should I use to give my Process some input?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can only read from an `InputStream`, so use that to catch the output of your process.

You write to an `OutputStream`, so use that to give the process your input.

You are using names that make sense in the context of the spawned process. But the API names make sense in the context of the parent process.

Here's another tip: if your process writes to standard error, be sure to read that too. If standard output or error pipes of the sub-process are full (because your parent Java process isn't consuming them), the child process will block on its `write()` calls.

Comment: I find it very confising to, not to say flawed. Isn't it a core Object-Oriented design-pattern to name methods in the context of the object that offers this method?

Answer (score 9):

I always ignore the names and look at what's returned. If your code has an `OutputStream`, you can *write* to it - which means it's the *input* for the other process. If your code has an `InputStream`, you can *read* from it - which means it's the *output* or error for the other process.

Fortunately, the compiler will tell you if you're doing the wrong thing - you've got the data you want to provde, so you've got to write it to the stream, which means it's *got* to be the `OutputStream`.

Answer (score 3):

The getOutputStream is input *to* the process.  The getInputStream is output read *from* the process.

Refer to the [JavaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) if it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the doc. This is indeed completely messing around, compared to other framework that make it in the "obvious" way, so the doc is your friend.

```
public abstract OutputStream getOutputStream()
> Gets the output stream of the subprocess. Output to the stream is piped into the standard input stream of the process
```

Should have been too simple to have:

```
public abstract InputStream getInputStream()
> Gets the standarinput stream of the subprocess. Output to the stream is piped into the standard input stream of the process
```